# Use Foreman to Start Rack App Located in Different Directory

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, foreman, procfile

I have a Procfile setup that is running a number of processes successfully:

```
# /Procfile
redis: bundle exec redis-server
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq -v -C ./config.yml
forward: forward 4567 mock-api
```

I need to add one more process - a Sinatra app that lives in a different directory on my machine. If I cd to the directory, I can start it from the Terminal with:

```
$ rackup -p 4567
```

And I can start it from a different directory using the Terminal with:

```
$ sh -c 'cd /Path/to/project/ && exec rackup -p 4567'
```

But how should I do this using foreman. I have tried adding the following, but it fails silently:

```
mock-api: sh -c 'cd /Path/to/project/ && exec rackup -p 4567'
```

Is this even possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of all the stupid things ...

It was failing because of the hyphen in the process name.